# C# + База данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Есть база данных, построенная на SQL Server, и приложение на C#. Каким образом можно вытащить значение с базы данных и провести с ним манипуляции, а потом его запихнуть обратно в базу?

Answer (score 3):

Вам как раз не стоит обращать внимание на LINQ2SQL, так как эта технология является устаревшей, и сама Microsoft взамен рекомендует использовать Entity Framework в силу того, что последний является более современной и прогрессивной технологией. Однако вначале я бы советовал вам поработать с ADO.NET чтобы лучше понять работу с базами данных, а не действовать наощупь, когда большую часть работы за вас выполняет ORM.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам надо сделать что-то серьёзное, а не просто модифицировать пару значений, не обойтись без ORM. Например, [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) или [NHibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/).

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю свои пять копеек. А что за задача? Можно же написать хранимку, выполняющую нужные модифиации, при том пакетно. а уже потом вызывать ее откуда Вам надо. Если, конечно, у Вас там ничего замудренного.

Comment: Проект не большой - курсовой. Задача такая: есть 3 таблицы БД, "Поезд, Вагон и Каса" нужно вытащить пару значений, а именно: из таблицы "Поезд.общее_количество_билетов" отнять "Каса.количество_заказаных_билетов". Вот собственно и всё, почему не хочу работать с хранимыми процедурами:
1) Опыт не большой;
2) На сколько мне известно, в хранимую процедуру нужно передавать все значении что есть в таблице, а это сильно усложняет задачу.

Comment: В хранимую процедуру не надо передвавать таблицы, Вы из нее можете можете обращаться к нужной таблице(ам), получать данные и обрабатывать так как Вам позволят средства СУБД. Но, судя по Вашей формулировке задачи, все модификации сводится к вычитанию одного поля из другого, с чем справится банальный SELECT, а его можно обернуть в представление (в случае если вы работаете с MS SQL Server)

Comment: Достаточно будет всего лишь передать идентификатор поезда (возможно и нужного вагона - по ситуации) - остальное "хранимка" вычислит сама и "вернет" вам результат. Если это действительно и все, что вам надо от бд, то использование орм, как "из пушки по воробьям".

Comment: человеку, слабо знакомому с БД, начинать с ORM вообще очень вредно